# Im getting Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, reference, undefined

I am also having the "undefined reference to ERPSGame()" error as well as the "Id returned 1 exit status". Did I declare something wrong? I am using Orwell Dev C++.
What seems to be the problem? Is it my compiler ?
Check out the whole code:

```
    /* GameBox BETA v0.2 */

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void ERPS();
    void Menu();
    void BJack();
    void Log();
    int ERPSGame();
    void ERPSInstruct();


    int main() {
    char Choice;
    system("cls");

printf("\t\t Welcome to Mark and Leroy's GameBox BETA v0.2 \n\n\n");
printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("\t _________________________________________________________\n");
printf("\t ||_____________________________________________________|| \n");
printf("\t ||                                       \t\t|| \n");
printf("\t ||                                       \t\t|| \n");
printf("\t ||                                       \t\t|| \n");
printf("\t ||\t Please press 'A' to continue to the menu\t||\n");
printf("\t ||\t                                         \t||\n");
printf("\t ||\t Otherwise, press 'F' to exit the program\t||\n");
printf("\t ||_____________________________________________________|| \n");
printf("\t ||_____________________________________________________||\n");
printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
/* Drawing Starts Here */

printf("\t\t ========================================\n");
printf("\t\t ||                                    || \n");
printf("\t\t ||          ||===============         || \n");
printf("\t\t ||          ||                        || \n");
printf("\t\t ||          ||         =======        || \n");
printf("\t\t ||          ||     Gamebox  ||        || \n");
printf("\t\t ||          ||   BETA v0.2  ||        || \n");
printf("\t\t ||          ||==============||        || \n");
printf("\t\t ||                                    || \n");
printf("\t\t ||      ||====  ||====||  ==    ==    || \n");
printf("\t\t ||      ||   || ||    ||   ==  ==     || \n");
printf("\t\t ||      ||===|| ||    ||     ==       || \n");
printf("\t\t ||      ||___|| ||====||   ==  ==     || \n");
printf("\t\t ||                        ==    ==    || \n");
printf("\t\t ||   Artwork by: Mark Sanchez         || \n");
printf("\t\t ========================================\n");

/* Drawing Ends Here */
    scanf("%c", &Choice);

        switch (Choice) {

            case'A':case'a':{

                Menu();
                break;

            }

            case'F':case'f':{
                exit(0);
            }

            default: {
                main();
            }

        }

        return 0;
   }

    void Menu() {
char Choice1;
system("cls");
printf("\t\t Welcome to Mark and Leroy's GameBox BETA v0.2 \n\n\n");
printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
printf("\t\t Press 'R' to play the Enhanced Rock-Paper-Scissors game\n\n\n");
printf("\t\t Press 'B'to play Blackjack\n\n\n");
printf("\t\t Press 'C' to view the changelog\n\n\n");   
printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    scanf("%c", &Choice1);

switch(Choice1) {
    case'R':case'r': {
        ERPS();
        break;
    }
    case'B':case'b': {
        BJack();
        break;
    }
    case'C':case'c': {
        Log();
        break;
    }
    default: {
        Menu();
    }
}

    }



    void ERPS() {
system("cls");

    char Instruct1;
    char Instruct2;
    /* Menu of ERPS */
    printf("\t\t\t Welcome to ENHANCED Rock Paper Scissors\n\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\t Press A to start the game\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\t Press S to view the instructions\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\t Press 'P' to return to the main menu\n");
    scanf("%c", &Instruct1);
    scanf("%c", &Instruct2);

    switch(Instruct2) {
        case'A':case'a': {
            ERPSGame();
            break;
        }
        case'S':case's': {
            ERPSInstruct();
            break;

        }
        case'P':case'p': {
            Menu();
            break;

        }
        default:{
            ERPS();
        }
    }

   }


    int rand_i(int n)
    {
int rand_max = RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % n);
int ret;
while ((ret = rand()) >= rand_max);
return ret/(rand_max / n);
    }

    int weighed_rand(int *tbl, int len)
    {
int i, sum, r;
for (i = 0, sum = 0; i < len; sum += tbl[i++]);
if (!sum) return rand_i(len);

r = rand_i(sum) + 1;
for (i = 0; i < len && (r -= tbl[i]) > 0; i++);
return i;
   }



     int ERPSGame(int argc, const char *argv[]) /* THIS IS THE ERPSGame */
     {
char umove[10], cmove[10], line[255];
int user, comp;
int tbl[]={0,0,0};
int tbllen=3;
printf("Hello, Welcome to rock-paper-scissors\nBy The Elite Noob\n");
      mainloop:
while(1)
{ // infinite loop :)
    printf("\n\nPlease type in 1 for Rock, 2 For Paper, 3 for Scissors, 4 to quit\n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    comp = (weighed_rand(tbl, tbllen) + 1) % 3;
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);   
    while(sscanf(line, "%d", &user) != 1) //1 match of defined specifier on input line
    { 
        printf("You have not entered an integer.\n");
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    }               
    if( (user > 4) || (user < 1) )
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid number!\n");
        continue;
    }
    switch (comp)
    {
        case 1 :
            strcpy(cmove, "Rock");
            break;
        case 2 :
            strcpy(cmove, "Paper");
            break;
        case 3 :
            strcpy(cmove, "Scissors");
            break;
        default :
            printf("Computer Error, set comp=1\n");
            comp=1;
            strcpy(cmove, "Rock");
            break;
    }
    switch (user)
    {
        case 1 :
            strcpy(umove, "Rock");
            break;
        case 2 :
            strcpy(umove, "Paper");
            break;
        case 3 :
            strcpy(umove, "Scissors");
            break;
        case 4 :
            printf("Goodbye! Thanks for playing!\n");
            return 0;
        default :
            printf("Error, user number not between 1-4 exiting...");
            goto mainloop;
    }
    if( (user+1)%3 == comp )
    {
        printf("Comp Played: %s\nYou Played: %s\nSorry, You Lost!\n", cmove, umove);
    }   
    else if(comp == user)
    {
        printf("Comp Played: %s\nYou Played: %s\nYou Tied :p\n", cmove, umove);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Comp Played: %s\nYou Played: %s\nYay, You Won!\n", cmove, umove);
    }
    tbl[user-1]++;
}
    }




void ERPSInstruct() {
system("cls");
char Instruct3;

printf("\t\t\t Instructions of the Game \n\n");
printf("\t\t\t There will be 5 choices to choose from\n");
printf("\t\t\t 1. Rock\n");
printf("\t\t\t 2. Paper\n");
printf("\t\t\t 3. Scissors\n");
printf("\t\t\t 4. Lizard\n");
printf("\t\t\t 5. Spock\n\n\n\n");

printf("\t\t This is the mechanism of the choices: \n\n");
printf("\t\t Scissor cuts paper. \n\n");    
printf("\t\t Paper covers rock. \n\n");
printf("\t\t Rock crushes lizard. \n\n");
printf("\t\t Lizard poisons spock. \n\n");
printf("\t\t Spock smashes scissors. \n\n");
printf("\t\t Scissors decapitate lizard. \n\n");
printf("\t\t Lizard eats paper. \n\n");
printf("\t\t Paper disproves spock. \n\n");
printf("\t\t Spock vaporizes rock. \n\n");
printf("\t\t Rock crushes scissors. \n\n");

printf("\t\t\t Press 'P' to return to the menu\n");
    scanf("%c", &Instruct3);

    switch(Instruct3) {
        case'P':case'p': {
            Menu();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            ERPSInstruct();
        }
    }

 }















void BJack() {
system("cls");

char Instruct2;


printf("BLACKJack \n\n\n");

printf("\t\t\t Press 'P' to return to the menu\n");
    scanf("%c", &Instruct2);
    switch(Instruct2) {
        case'P':case'p': {
            Menu();
            break;

        }
        default: {
            BJack();
            break;
        }
    }
getch();
}
void Log() {

system("cls");

char Instruct3;
printf("CHANGELOG: \n\n\n");
printf(" 0.1 -- Fixed a bug wherein the program forces\n to do 'default' upon choosing a game\n\n\n");
printf("-----------------------------------------------\n\n");
printf(" 0.2 -- Fixed display in CMD: Added a few dividers \nas well as correcting a few grammatical mistakes\n");
printf(" Added awesome graphics \n\n\n");
printf("-----------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\t Press 'P' to return to the menu\n");
    scanf("%c", &Instruct3);
    switch(Instruct3) {
        case'P':case'p': {
            Menu();
            break;

        }
        default: {
            Log();
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Is it my way of declaring ERPSGame? I used int.

Comment: Are you trying to have your program skip all of the other code and start executing at `ERPSGame` instead of `main`?

Comment: No, if the program is working, youll start with the menu then so on and on

Comment: Ok, like mahaendrian b said, the declaration and definition of `ERPSGame` don't match. I suggest removing the arguments in the definition of `ERPSGame`, because you're neither passing any arguments to it, not using any of the arguments.

Comment: I removed the arguments inside ERPSGame but the error is still the same

Comment: Your use of `mainloop: while (1) { ...; if (...) goto mainloop; ...; }` is weird; you should just use `continue`: `while (1) { ...; if (...) continue; ... }`.  You should error check your inputs (`fgets()` etc); people should be able to type EOF and have the program quit gracefully.  However, fixing these has no effect on your linking problem.  It just means that the linking problem is only one of the issues you should fix.

Comment: Also, the outdentation and indentation of your code is eccentric.  Please use an orthodox layout when you ask questions on SO (or when you submit homework) for the sake of everyone's sanity.

Comment: Sorry for the weird code layout, I usually fix my code once it's finished.

Comment: Pro tip: it is actually easier to keep it correctly formatted as you write the code than to reformat it later.  It is also easier to debug if it is readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function declaration is not matched with function definition.

Declaration:

```
int ERPSGame();
```

Definition

```
int ERPSGame(int argc, const char *argv[])
```

In Dev-C++, under Tools -> Compiler Options, put "-Wall" in the "...commands when calling compiler" box. It will be helpful for you to get warnings and do effective coding and saves your time too.

Comment: what should I do to match it?

Comment: @Minus Change the definition to int ERPSGame(){}.

Comment: …or even better: to `int ERPSGame(void){}` (same—and more important—for the declaration).

Answer (score 0):

When you take in instruct1 and then use instruct2 in the switch...

```
    scanf("%c", &Instruct1);
scanf("%c", &Instruct2);

switch(Instruct2) {
    case'A':case'a': {
        ERPSGame();
```

This could be giving you an odd value given the fact that users response is in instruct1. Potentially.

Comment: I removed Instruct1 but yet the problem is still the same