# How to add more choices in Rock Paper Scissors using this code in C

Tags: c

Now that I got this program running, The code I have here is for Rock Paper and Scissors only.
I've managed to include the inputs for Lizard and Spock but I don't know how to make the CPU (randomly) chose lizard and spock as well as making the program think that lizards poison spock etc.

Here is the segment of the code:

This is for random picking of CPUmove:

```
int rand_i(int n)
{
    int rand_max = RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % n);
    int ret;
    while ((ret = rand()) >= rand_max);
    return ret/(rand_max / n);
}

int weighed_rand(int *tbl, int len)
{
    int i, sum, r;
    for (i = 0, sum = 0; i < len; sum += tbl[i++]);
    if (!sum) return rand_i(len);

    r = rand_i(sum) + 1;
    for (i = 0; i < len && (r -= tbl[i]) > 0; i++);
    return i;
}
```

This is the game proper including the inputs:

```
int ERPSGame()
{
    system("cls");
    char CPUmove[10], Usermove[10], line[255];
    int user, comp;
    int tbl[]={0,0,0};
    int tbllen=3;
    printf("Hello, Welcome to Enhanced Rock Paper Scissors\nBy Mark Sanchez\n");
    mainloop:
    while(1)
    { // infinite loop :)
        printf("\n\nPlease type in 1 for Rock, 2 For Paper, 3 for Scissors, 4 for Lizard \nand 5 for Spock. 0 to quit\n");
        srand(time(NULL));
        comp = (weighed_rand(tbl, tbllen) + 1) % 5;
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);   
        while(sscanf(line, "%d", &user) != 1) //1 match of defined specifier on input line
        { 
            printf("You have not entered an integer.\n");
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        }               
        if( (user > 5) || (user < 1) )
        {
            printf("Please enter a valid number!\n");
            continue;
        }
        switch (comp)
        {
            case 1 :
            strcpy(Usermove, "Rock");
            break;
            case 2 :
            strcpy(Usermove, "Paper");
            break;
            case 3 :
            strcpy(Usermove, "Scissors");
            break;
            case 4 :
            strcpy(Usermove, "Lizard");
            break;
            case 5 :
            strcpy(Usermove, "Spock");
            break;
            default :
            printf("Computer Error, set comp=1\n");
            comp=1;
            strcpy(Usermove, "Rock");
            break;
        }
        switch (user)
        {
            case 1 :
            strcpy(CPUmove, "Rock");
            break;
            case 2 :
            strcpy(CPUmove, "Paper");
            break;
            case 3 :
            strcpy(CPUmove, "Scissors");
            break;
            case 4 :
            strcpy(CPUmove, "Lizard");
            break;
            case 5 :
            strcpy(CPUmove, "Spock");
            break;
            case 0 :
            printf("Goodbye! Thanks for playing!\n");
            return 0;
            default :
            printf("Error, your number is not between 1-5 exiting...");
            goto mainloop;
        }
        if( (user+1)%3 == comp )
        {
            printf("Comp Played: %s\nYou Played: %s\nSorry, You Lost!\n", Usermove, CPUmove);
        }   
        else if(comp == user)
        {
            printf("Comp Played: %s\nYou Played: %s\nYou Tied :p\n", Usermove, CPUmove);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Comp Played: %s\nYou Played: %s\nYay, You Won!\n", Usermove, CPUmove);
        }
        tbl[user-1]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of apologise why not fix it and correct the indentation.

Comment: Did you try to debug and trace the code?

Comment: I'm doing a lot of things and I will fix my code once I'm done with it. :)

@alk I tried experimenting with the values but I do not know what they are at least most of them

Comment: @Minus - If you get into the habit of doing things right in the first place it becomes second nature

Comment: Yes I know that, and this project is an exception for it :\ I don't have time for arranging it now

Comment: As I already used up my vote-for-closure-option, could someone please close this as being a 100% duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25102417/694576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of an advice: Keep everything as numbers for as long as possible. As you maybe noticed, handling strings is quite tedious.
So you have inputs of both cpu and user. Now this makes two numbers.. Then its time for a switch or therealike:

```
switch (user)
case 1: 
  if (cpu==1){
    printf('draw');
  }elseif (cpu==2 || cpu==3 || cpu==4){
    printf('pc won');
  }else{
   printf('congrats, you made it!');
  }
case 2:
...
```

Or like you did allready try to get an easy calculation to represent the winning and loosing (like your `(user+1)%3 == comp`) which I would do as next step to make it more elegant. For that, write donw all combinations and think of a good way to order the fields to then do something like the modulo or some division.

edit: to print the numbers into something like you played this, pc played that, I'd suggest a function doing that for you. So you give it the number(s) and it will either directly print the results, or will give you the strings for printing.

Comment: Well, I haven't thought of that! Good answer, thanks